# Scalacheck: Generate list corresponding to list of generators

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I want to generate a list of integers corresponding to a list of generators in `ScalaCheck`.

```
    import org.scalacheck._
    import Arbitrary.arbitrary

    val smallInt = Gen.choose(0,10)
    val bigInt = Gen.choose(1000, 1000000)
    val zeroOrOneInt = Gen.choose(0, 1)
    val smallEvenInt = smallInt suchThat (_ % 2 == 0)

    val gens = List(smallInt, bigInt, zeroOrOneInt, smallEvenInt)
    //val listGen: Gen[Int] = ??
    //println(listGen.sample) //should print something like List(2, 2000, 0, 6)
```

For the given `gens`, I would like to create a generator `listGen` whose valid sample can be `List(2, 2000, 0, 6)`.
Here is my first attempt using tuples.

```
    val gensTuple = (smallInt, bigInt, zeroOrOneInt, smallEvenInt)
    val tupleGen = for {
        a <- gensTuple._1
        b <- gensTuple._2
        c <- gensTuple._3
        d <- gensTuple._4
    } yield (a, b, c, d)

    println(tupleGen.sample) // prints Some((1,318091,0,6))
```

This works, but I don't want to use tuples since the list of generators(`gens`) is created dynamically
and the size of the list is not fixed. Is there a way to do it with Lists?

I want the use the generator of the list(`listGen`) in scalacheck `forAll` property checking.

This looks like a toy problem but this is
the best I could do to create a standalone snippet reproducing the actual issue I am
facing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about using the `Gen.sequence` method? It transforms an `Iterable[Gen[T]]` into a `Gen[C[T]]`, where `C` can be `List`:

```
  def sequence[C[_],T](gs: Iterable[Gen[T]])(implicit b: Buildable[T,C]): Gen[C[T]] = 
     ...
```

Comment: Works fine! I had to explicitly add the implicit argument because of ambiguity with another method. `val listGen = Gen.sequence(gens)(util.Buildable.buildableList)`

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Gen.sequence`, but be careful as it will try to return a `java.util.ArrayList[T]` if you don't fully parameterize it ([bug](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/issues/131)).

Full working example:

```
def genIntList(): Gen[List[Int]] = {

  val gens = List(Gen.chooseNum(1, 2), Gen.chooseNum(3, 4))

  Gen.sequence[List[Int], Int](gens)
}

println(genIntList.sample.get) // prints: List(1,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Please disregard, this doesn't answer the asker's question

---

I can't comment on posts yet, so I'll have to venture a guess here. I presume the function 'sample' applies to the generators

Any reason why you can't do:

```
gens map (t=>t.sample)
```

Comment: I don't want create samples manually. It will be done by `scalacheck` when I use the generator as `forAll(listGen){ list => <list property> }`

Comment: Ah sorry about that, didn't realise that scalacheck creates the samples

Answer (score 0):

For a more theoretical answer:  the method you want is `traverse`, which is equivalent to `sequence compose map` although it might be more efficient.  It is of the general form:

```
def traverse[C[_]: Traverse, F[_]: Applicative, A, B](f: A => F[B], t: C[A]): F[C[B]]
```

It behaves like `map` but allows you to carry around some extra `Applicative` structure during the traversal, sequencing it along the way.